# Correcting for spatial autocorrelation in community dissimilarity datasets

Tags: r, matrix, spatial, correlation

I have a community assembly dataset with 299 species at 15 sites. Im interested in correcting for the effect of spatial autocorrelation on beta-diversity (or species turnover). [Dataset here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s65k8xx9bj8q0pl/Spatial%20Autocorrelation.csv?dl=0)

There is an obvious effect of spatial distance between the sites and community dissimilarity. I have a completed a mantel correlogram to show this effect but now I’m a bit stuck on how to account for this effect or correct for beta diversity analyzes.  And more importantly how does the effect of distance between sites compare to my environmental effect (`precip`)

```
#load libraries 
library (vegan)
library (fossil)
#load datasets
spp.list<-read.csv('Spatial Autocorrelation.csv', header=T)
rownames(spp.list)=spp.list$Site
sites.xy= spp.list[,(2:3)]
precip= spp.list[,(4)]
spp.list<-spp.list[,(5:303)]

#check for spatial autocorrelation and environmental correlation using Mantel Test

#build a species dissimilarity matrix 
dist.mat=vegdist (spp.list)

#build a geographic distance matrix for sites
geo.dist.mat=earth.dist(sites.xy)

#build a distance matrix for precip values
precip.dist <-dist (precip)
#identify the correlations between two matrices Matel Correlelogram
correlog<-mantel.correlog( dist.mat, geo.dist.mat, nperm=999 )
summary(correlog)
correlog
plot (correlog)
```

[image]
    #partial Mantel Test including both distance and precipitation differences 
    library (ecodist)
    natt.pmgram<-pmgram (dist.mat, geo.dist.mat, precip.dist, nperm=999)
    plot (natt.pmgram)
[image]

Im not sure how to interpret these correlograms. Does anyone have any suggestions/explanations? and can these analyses be used to correct for the obvious spatial auto-correlation issues in my dataset?